# Can yaws be used in embedded mode while not putting it in relx or in included_applications?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, yaws

Currently I am able to use `yaws` in embedded mode by either:

1. adding `{yaws, load}` in the relx section of rebar.config.
2. adding `yaws` to `included_applications` section in `*.app.src`.

Method #1 was the suggested way in [YAWS Embedded as dependence in rebar3 issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32364617/yaws-embedded-as-dependence-in-rebar3-issue). Method #2 is not recommended by: https://learnyousomeerlang.com/the-count-of-applications#included-applications

I want to be able to start `yaws` in embedded mode while putting it in `applications` section in `*.app.src`.

The reason for this question is that I have an application which would have multiple such yaws applications in the `applications` section in `*.app.src`. To clarify, I have `main_app` which would have something like: `{applications, [..., YawsEmbeddedApp1, YawsEmbeddedApp2, ...]}` in `main_app.app.src`. There is also a chance that this isn't possible: from http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2012-May/066669.html, it appears that it wasn't possible in 2012. But I think that shouldn't be the case if I can start embedded yaws by
using `*.app.src`>`applications`.

Comment: Why not use one Yaws application configured with multiple virtual servers?

Comment: The two YawsEmbeddedApps are standalone applications. The main_app is for dev / testing.

Comment: So the only possible solution I can think of now is to convert both embedded apps to standalone apps, and that way ultimately the main_app could be configured to be one Yaws application with multiple virtual servers

Comment: The mailing list answer from May 2012 that you linked to is still accurate. I think using multiple virtual servers is your best bet.

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't find any other option so going to go with this :)